# How to change swagger-ui.html default path

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I wanna change my **swagger-ui** path from `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` to
`localhost:8080/myapi/swagger-ui.html` in `springboot` 
redirect is helpless to me

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1080

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Swagger-ui URL prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712519/how-to-change-swagger-ui-url-prefix)

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50713024/9437031

Answer (score 16):

In the application.properties of Spring Boot

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui-custom.html
```

in your case it will be

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/myapi/swagger-ui.html
```

Comment: Hey! This doesn't work for me. Do you know if there are any other places that take precedence or if I may need to enable something?

Comment: @MarcinK. are you using springdoc or springfox?

Comment: @Cugomastik Hey! Thanks for being helpful, but sadly I no longer have access to this project. Sadly because I would love to provide the solution that helped me to the others.

Answer (score 3):

if for some reason you don't want redirect to `/swagger-ui.html` you can set itself contents as home view, setting an index.html at resources/static/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome to another awesome Microservice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.body.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="/swagger-ui.html" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px"></object>';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

then accessing to your http://localhost:8080/ you will see your swagger docs.

finally you can customize path and .html file using:

```
registry.addViewController("/swagger").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
```

like suggests [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54260515/9310852)

Answer (score 3):

You can modify springfox properties in application.properties

For example, to edit the base-url

```
springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.base-url=documentation
```

For e.g. setting it to `/documentation` will put swagger-ui at `/documentation/swagger-ui/index.html`

Comment: getting error: undefined http://localhost:8080/custom-path/v2/api-docs when using this to set swagger custom path

Comment: is it possible to have just /documentation? So it will be "localhost:8080/documentation" no "swagger-ui" after documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add, for example, `documentation` prefix - You can do like this for path `http://localhost:8080/documentation/swagger-ui.html`:

> kotlin

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("your.package.config")
@Import(value = [BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration::class])
class SwaggerConfiguration(
    private val swaggerContactProp: SwaggerContactProp, private val swaggerProp: SwaggerProp
) : WebMvcConfigurationSupport() {

    // https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/
    @Bean
    fun api(): Docket = Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .groupName("Cards")
        .apiInfo(getApiInfo())
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your.controllers.folder"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()

    private fun getApiInfo(): ApiInfo {
        val contact = Contact(swaggerContactProp.name, swaggerContactProp.url, swaggerContactProp.mail)
        return ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title(swaggerProp.title)
            .description(swaggerProp.description)
            .version(swaggerProp.version)
            .contact(contact)
            .build()
    }

    override fun addViewControllers(registry: ViewControllerRegistry) {
        with(registry) {
            addRedirectViewController("/documentation/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs").setKeepQueryParams(true)
            addRedirectViewController(
                "/documentation/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui"
            )
            addRedirectViewController(
                "/documentation/swagger-resources/configuration/security", "/swagger-resources/configuration/security"
            )
            addRedirectViewController("/documentation/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources")
        }
    }

    override fun addResourceHandlers(registry: ResourceHandlerRegistry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/documentation/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/")
    }
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "swagger")
@ConstructorBinding
data class SwaggerProp(val title: String, val description: String, val version: String)

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "swagger.contact")
@ConstructorBinding
data class SwaggerContactProp(val mail: String, val url: String, val name: String)
```

and in `applicatiom.yml`:

```
swagger:
  title: Cards
  version: 1.0
  description: Documentation for API
  contact:
    mail: email@gmail.com
    url: some-url.com
    name: COLABA card
```

Also don't forget to add in `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
                implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:$swagger")
                implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:$swagger")
                implementation("io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:$swagger")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found several possible solutions for myself. Maybe it will be helpful for somebody else.

---

#### Set `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` directly

The straightforward way is to set property `springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/custom/path`. It will work perfectly if you can hardcode `swagger` path in your application.

---

#### Override `springdoc.swagger-ui.path` property

You can change default `swagger-ui` path programmatically using `ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent>`. The idea is simple -  override `springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/custom/path` before your Spring Boot application starts.

```java
@Component
public class SwaggerConfiguration implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("springdoc.swagger-ui.path", swaggerPath());
        environment.getPropertySources()
                .addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("programmatically", props));
    }

    private String swaggerPath() {
        return "/swagger/path"; //todo: implement your logic here.
    }
}
```

In this case, you must register the listener before your application start:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "APIs", version = "0.0.1", description = "APIs v0.0.1"))
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        application.addListeners(new SwaggerConfiguration());
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

---

#### Redirect using controller

You can also register your own controller and make a simple redirect as suggested [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68470105/how-do-i-configure-a-custom-url-for-the-springdoc-swagger-ui-html-page/69882984).

Redirect code for `Spring WebFlux` applications:

```
@RestController
public class SwaggerEndpoint {

    @GetMapping("/custom/path")
    public Mono<Void> api(ServerHttpResponse response) {
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT);
        response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/swagger-ui.html"));
        return response.setComplete();
    }
}
```

The problem with such an approach - your server will still respond if you call it by address `"/swagger-ui.html"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it worked for me

```
package com.swagger.api.redirect;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

public class SwaggerApiReDirector implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/configuration/ui", "/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/configuration/security", "/configuration/security");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/swagger-resources/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation", "/documentation/swagger-ui.html");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/", "/documentation/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/documentation/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using spring boot then please update 
application.properties file and write here

```
server.servlet.context-path=/myapi
```

it will redirect you as you want.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that will prepend /myapi to all paths i.e. it will also change any REST controller from /myapi/something/something2 to /myapi/myapi/something/something2.