# Swagger Base URL is wrong for my application deployed on AWS

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a Spring Boot application deployed and configured as AWS Route 53 > AWS Load Balance -> 2 EC2 instances which hosted the Spring Boot application.

The URL for the Swagger is
**https**://applicationXYZ.company.net/release/swagger-ui.html

I'm able to see the page without any issue. But we can't use the 'Tryout' feature because the Base URL is wrong.

On top of the page I do see information as
[ Base URL: service/release]

[image]

I have no idea where 'service' became my base URL. I also hit api-docs and also see 'server' in 'host' field.

Could you please help on this?

Note: I'm using Spring Boot Starter 2.0.8.RELEASE and Swagger 2.9.2 (without any Spring Security)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try to make a redirect,

```
//Do redirection inside controller
@RequestMapping("/swagger")
public String greeting() {
    return "redirect:/swagger-ui.html";
}
```

you can try to add bean too, inside main method,

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction() {
    return route(GET("/swagger"), req ->
        ServerResponse.temporaryRedirect(URI.create("swagger-ui.html")).build());
}
```

refer: [How to change Swagger-ui URL prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712519/how-to-change-swagger-ui-url-prefix)