# Removing v1 from swagger ui

Tags: swagger, versioning, spring-restcontroller

I have my RestController with below code

[RestControllerCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8ocY.png)

while my swagger launching it is showing like below

[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nt7n.png)

I don't want v1 into Swagger UI , but somehow my endpoint should get called via 'v1' including. like (http://localhost:8080/v1/myFirstMessage).

Is there any way fo this..?

Comment: Do you have swagger.json file inside project folder?

Comment: Hi @Paresh Gami : Thanks for your interest. I don't have any json file inside project folder

Comment: Which technology you are using for API development?

Comment: I am using Java Spring Boot

Comment: Looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712519/how-to-change-swagger-ui-url-prefix

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you have 'v1' in your GetMapping.
Your get mapping should be something like this instead `@GetMapping("/myFirstMessage")`

[image]