# How to change the Swagger UI path for a Spring Boot app using Sprinfgox?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I need to remove the *"/swagger-ui"* part from the Swagger UI URL. So far I have seen examples of how to add a prefix prior to the *"/swagger-ui"* such as *"/prefix/swagger-ui"* but **I want to remove it completely** and just have the prefix.

```
localhost:8080/swagger-ui -> localhost:8080/test
```

I have tried adding the following two to the `.properties` file but had no luck:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/test

springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.base-url=test
```

-spring-boot version: **2.5.6**

I am using the below dependency for Springfox:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am wondering if there is any other way.

Comment: Do you use Springfox or Springdoc?

Comment: Hi Helen, good question. I am using Springfox and tried springfox.documentation.swagger-ui.base-url=test but no luck there as well.

Comment: What version of Springfox? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66640426/113116) contains the relevant configs for v. 3.0.0. 2.x versions will probably need [something like this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1080#issuecomment-169185653).

Comment: I edited the question to show both the spring boot and spring fox versions. I will check both answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Helen the second suggestion is still having "swagger-ui" keywords in the url so wont do anything good for me. However, the first is very informative.